# how to select multiple sum() quantity

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to select the sum of quantity(qty) from orders table,there are 2 category dirham (kupon_id = 2) and dinar (kupon_id = 1)

[image]

i already got the sum of kupon_id = 2,but i dont know how to get sum of qty where kupon_id = 1,here the example :

[image]

my model :

```
$this->db->join('
(
  SELECT sum(co.qty) as total_dirham,co.user_id
  from ci_order co 
  where co.kupon_id = 2 group by co.user_id
  ) as co
','co.user_id=cug.user_id','left');
```

i tried join the same table with difference WHERE condition but its wrong :

```
  $this->db->join('
(
  SELECT sum(co.qty) as total_dirham,co.user_id
  from ci_order co 
  where co.kupon_id = 2 group by co.user_id
  ) as co
','co.user_id=cug.user_id','left');
  $this->db->join('
(
  SELECT sum(co.qty) as total_dinar,co.user_id
  from ci_order co 
  where co.kupon_id = 1 group by co.user_id
  ) as co
','co.user_id=cug.user_id','left');
```

update model :

```
$this->db->join('
(
  SELECT sum(co.qty) as total,co.user_id, co.kupon_id
  from ci_order co 
  group by co.user_id, co.kupon_id
  ) as co
  
','co.user_id=cug.user_id','left');
```

[image]

the result shows both quantity of the id at difference row,i want it to show at Dinar,example like this :

[image]

Comment: Try this: `SELECT sum(co.qty) as total_dinar, co.kupon_id, co.user_id
  from ci_order co 
  group by co.kupon_id,  co.user_id`. you should get multiple rows, each one showing the sum for that kupon ID. if it helps let me know, I'll add it as an answer properly

Comment: ok i got multilpe rows

Comment: how to separate the `sum(co.qty) as ` ?

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean by "separate" it? You have 1 row per koupon...how much more separate do you want?

Comment: Re your screenshots...that's an issue with how you present the data. That's separate from how you write the query. The query I posted gets you the data you want, which is what you asked for. How you then display it is up to you, you can change your code for that however you like. I can't tell you what changes to make because I can't see that part of your code. But anyway that's really a separate question. Originally you asked how to get the data. I showed you. So you should accept that answer, and then ask a new, separate question about the UI issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$this->db->join('
(
  SELECT 
    (select sum(qty) from ci_order where kupon_id = 2 and user_id = a.user_id) as total_dirham, 
    (select sum(qty) from ci_order where kupon_id = 1 and user_id = a.user_id) as total_dinar,
    a.user_id
  from ci_order a
) as co
','co.user_id=cug.user_id','left');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  sum(co.qty) as total_dinar, 
  co.kupon_id, 
  co.user_id   
from 
  ci_order co    
group by 
  co.kupon_id, 
  co.user_id
```

You should get multiple rows, each one showing the sum for that kupon ID.

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=40e2e56df44564a638147b8f6825b36d

(N.B. From the data sample provided it's unclear where `user_id` comes from, or what's in it, or whether you actually need to group by that or not, so I've left it in. For the demo I've added some dummy values in an invented field with that name.)